# Python Classes order of executing things

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm trying to make a window full of balloons disappear one-by-one (clicking on it),using python2, but I'm a little confused where I could capture my mouse events, in this moment, I'm not clicking anything, the code is attached. I'm inspired by the code at:
http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-canvas-find-withtag.htm,
but I'm trying to do my own arrangements.

I'm going a little bit confused how Python Classes, attributes, and events are related. Thanks for your ideas

```
class Baloons:
   def __init__(self,wdw, dimension):
        self.canvas= Canvas(wdw, width=dimension, height=dimension)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.update(self.canvas)
        self.click2(self.canvas)

   def click2(event, canvas):
       if  canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT):
            canvas.itemconfig(CURRENT, state="hidden")
            canvas.update_idletasks()
            canvas.after(200)
            canvas.delete("all")
            canvas.itemconfig(CURRENT, fill="red")
            self.update(canvas)
            self.click1(canvas)

   def update(self,canvas):
      for i in range(200):
          x, y = randint(0, 400-1), randint(0, 400-1)
          canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5, fill="red")

   def click1(self,canvas):
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click2(canvas))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     root=Tk()
     dimension = 200
     b=Baloons(root,dimension,delay)
     root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to make a window full of balloons disappear one-by-one (clicking on it)

That is not what your code is trying to do.  Your code is hiding it, destroying everything, trying to configure something you've destroyed, then recreating new objects.

To answer the question of how to make balloons disappear by clicking on them you can throw away about a fourth of your code.

Following is a working example. Mostly I just re-implemented `click2` to remove all of the code unrelated to deleting the item under the cursor. I also removed `click1` because I didn't see any reason to put the binding in a function. You only need to set up the binding once.

I also removed the need to pass `canvas` around. Since you're using objects, every method already has a way to access the canvas.

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import randint

class Baloons:
   def __init__(self,wdw, dimension):
        self.canvas= Canvas(wdw, width=dimension, height=dimension)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.update()
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.click2)

   def click2(self, event):
       item = self.canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT)
       if item:
           self.canvas.delete(item)

   def update(self):
      for i in range(200):
          x, y = randint(0, 400-1), randint(0, 400-1)
          self.canvas.create_oval(x-5, y-5, x+5, y+5, fill="red")

if __name__ == "__main__":
     root=Tk()
     dimension = 200
     b=Baloons(root,dimension)
     root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and patience. What do you think about using the canvas widget as a control panel of size, speed and color of the ballons, I'm checking how to avoid create another windows outside the main root window, what do you recommend ?. Thanks again